# using jquery wrap image cylinderically and show in 3d view, when dragged

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, html5-canvas

what we r making is a customisable mug for selling on our estore. it allows user to design it. for now we r using a flat/straightened 2d image of a cup on which customer can add texts, designs etc. we are using html 5 canvas for this to work.
what we want is to make our customer view a panoramic view of that mug. for that first we need is to pick whole canvas n make it as a single image(we have done this part), next one is to wrap that image around a cylindrical shape and give user ability to drag left-right n can see 3d panaromic view of the mug created.

i have googled and has seen various panoramic jquery plugins and what they use is just an array of images n showing it one by one when mouse is dragged on them. but this will not allow 3d spherical view, bcoz in mugs, we have a handle, which needs to be cared of. so, i think wrapping the image in cylinder would b fine, for starting.

scripting languages i am expecting to use is jquery, html5, css3

Comment: This is best done with 3D canvas contexts.  Here's an example with three.js that creates a panoramic cylinder.  You would add a texture to the cylinder representing your text/label:  http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/three/html5-canvas-webgl-cylinder-with-three-js/

Comment: thanks for this. one question-> can i add my big horizonatal image to it,copying from my canvas